# Pesquisar Valores, exibir e somar ao selecionar Input type='Select'

Tags: php

Estou fazendo um sistema de vendas com html e php banco Mysql.
E quero que ao selecionar o produto va somando os valores para no final o cliente vizualizar.
Estou usando javascript também.

Comment: Coloque o código que está a utilizar em ambas as partes para que a comunidade o consiga ajudar

Comment: Não conheço, ainda, esse Input type='Select'.  Conheço todos esses https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

Comment: sem postar código é bem difícil